# Multiple CSS declaration for same tag

Tags: html, css

I have a css style defined in a .js file for `<li>` tag in a page. I am trying to modify the html page without changing the existing css and js files and layout of the page. I want to insert the following code:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 18%; bottom: 6.4%; border-right-style: groove; border-right-width:2px; border-top-style: groove; border-top-width:2px; border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: 2px; padding-right: 0%; padding-top: 0%; margin-right: 0%; margin-top: 0%; position: fixed;">
    <ul class="MenuBarVertical">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But every `<li>` tag in the html page automatically picks the style from the existing css file. I don't want this for some `<li>` tags. I want a different css for `<li>` tags. Is it possible that I enclose those `<li>` tags under a `<div>` tag and add a class to the div tag and define a css specific for it which can override existing css for every `<li>` tag? I can override existing css by defining style in the `<li>` tag like `<li style="...">`. It works fine, but I have to add style in every `<li>` tag. I want to know if I add id or class to the parent  tag and write css for it somewhere in the page itself so as to override the existing style from .css file. What will be the code? How to declare such css in the  section? or should I declare in body?

I hope I am able to explain my problem. I want to know the possible ways to override css style for a tag.

Comment: adding a class would be the way to go. HTML nodes cannot have duplicate ids. You will run into issues later on

Comment: @Ankit You can add your styles in the head-section of your page. Try googling, mate. ;)

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some reading on [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the old rules, you need to define elements as specific as possible, like this:

```
div ul.MenuBarVertical li {...}
```

Even better if you can put an id to the div or ul elements (if you have a single such element on the page).
If nothing else works, you can use the `!important` parameter, but it's **strongly not recommended**.

Comment: !important is not not recommended. And putting the same id on multiple items is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @WhyMe He suggested putting an id on a *single* parent item (i.e., the `ul` or `div` around the `li`s).

Comment: I disagree with the second, sorry. I use !important, google dose so also. And for the second, I misread. Finaly, in the question he said he has more then one object or else he would not have an issue with an inline style.

Comment: @WhyMe Well, it's always easier to hit downvotes than to actually use your brain and/or read everything (especially in bold)...

Comment: It dose not answer the question at all. Seems to me a down vote is required.

Comment: @Shomz WhyMe is advocating *for* the use of `!important`. The "not not" in his comment is not a typo -- he read the bolded component of your answer correctly.

Comment: @Shmoz Should I put div ul.MenuBarVertical li {...} in head section or above div tag as mentioned by @ Christoph in earlier reply.

Comment: @apsillers Yeah, I figured it out in his latest comment... well, nothing to say there, if Google uses it...

Comment: @Ankit You can put it any way you like (separate CSS file, `style` block in the html head, whatever really), but make sure it's called *after* your existing CSS rule. And if you have one such element, I'd suggest putting an id to the parent div, so you have: `<div id="myID"><ul... etc ... </ul></div>` and the rule would be: `div#myID ul li`

Comment: @Shomz thanks. I will try it now and will inform you in 10 mins. Can you give any reference url where I can see how to declare it in the format you defined div ul.MenuBarVertical li {...} ? What is the term for such object oriented (".") declaration so as to search on Google? I am new in css domain.

Comment: Sure, no problem. `.` is used to denote a class (not OO), and `#` is used for IDs... See more [here](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php), for example, but there are tons of (probably better) resources online.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions:

1) use classes to define the properties you want. e.g.

```
<ul class="MenuBarVertical">
    <li class="other">Text 1</li>
    <li class="other">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

and then declare the styles you want to have on those `li`s. Declare it accordingly in your css file or to insert the ruleblock for this class with javascript, you can create a styleblock on the fly and add it to the head or use an existing one and append this rule.

2) Include an inline style block:

```
<ul class="MenuBarVertical">
<style scoped>
   .MenuBarVertical li{
       /*declarations here*/
   }
</style>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

The [scoped attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) is [rather new](http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped) and not recognized by browsers other than firefox and chrome, that's why I added the `.MenuBarVertical` part to further specify the `li`s you want to style ([increase specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)) and it will still work. Once `scoped` is recognized in all browser you could drop this and just write `li{...}`.

Please **don't**:

a) use inline styles - *bad*, always try to avoid this!

b) use `!important` - *even worse*, dont do this either!